# MvvmCross android linker kills binding

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I wrote simple adnroid app using MvvmCross. There are just two activicites. First one is LoginActivity which contains two text boxes and button. It is working fine when using on debug mode. It also works after archive when Linker is set to None. 
The problem is when I set Linker to SdkAssembilesOnly application run but when button is clicked nothing happens. I think that binding is not working.

```
  <Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Login"
      local:MvxBind="Click LoginCommand" />
```

While surfing internet I found some people uses LinkerPleaseInclude.cs - what should I add to this class to make it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - add a `LinkerPleaseInclude` class with the following method in it:

```
public void Include(Button button)
{
    button.Click += (s, e)
        => button.Text = $"{button.Text}";
}
```

Also make sure `LinkerPleaseInclude` has the `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute on it.

Comment: Great thanks alot it binding command. Inside button I have HttpClient request which doesn't work is it also about Linker?

Comment: I doubt it... I've never had issues with assembly linking removing HttpClient methods. I would need to see some code to know for sure though.

Comment: Inside command there is code using HttpClient.PostAsync, I have also added string property inside viewmodel to display any error or action - thats how I know button has been clicked becaue at the beginning of command method i write "ButtonClicked" but after few sec string disapear and nothing happend also added try catch but it doesnt show anything

Comment: Does the post succeed if you disable linking?

Comment: In that case it probably is a linking issue. One thing you can try is going to your Android project's properties -> Android Options -> Linker and put the name of your PCL assembly in the 'Skip linking assemblies' box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136222/discussion-between-miechooy-and-luke-pothier).